# Writing Ubuntu server image "Verification Failed"

Tags: sd-card, ubuntu, image, win32diskimager

I have tried googling for this to see if people have similar issues but found nothing.

I recently obtained a Raspberry Pi 4 (2gb), installed raspbian lite earlier today which all worked just fine, but I was really interested in setting up a 64-bit OS instead, I upgraded the kernel and was able to run/install things using chroot but since I would prefer having full 64-bit to be able to run systemd services through it, I was looking for an alternative.

I found out the Ubuntu server now has images for raspberry pi, including 64-bit ones, so I rushed over to their download page (https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) and downloaded 18.04.4 LTS (64-bit) for the RPi 4.

Attempting to install it using the Raspberry Pi Imager tool (I previously used for the raspbian image) everything from writing/verifying seems to happen at the right time duration, but in the end it will tell me the data on the sd card does not match what was written to it.

I gave it multiple attempts, and even tried multiple images (18.04.4 LTS as well as 19.10 (both 64-bit) and 18.04 32-bit version) all of them gave me the same result.

Playing around in the RPi Imager, I noticed there are also default options in there for installing the Ubuntu server, so I attempted using that option instead, but I was unlucky again as it gave me the same result.

Looking at the Ubuntu installation page, they are using Win32DiskImager so I figured I would give that a shot. The same thing happens (it instantly fails verification in "sector 2048").

Afraid somehow the SD-card or my adapter broke in the meantime, I figured I would try writing Raspbian Lite to it once more, and success! So this means it has to be the image file right? It's a 16gb Samsung SD card if that helps.

I am clueless on how to proceed, and as I said before can't find anyone encountering similar issues

Comment: searched and found https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/109320/raspberry-pi-imager-failing-to-verify-ubuntu-image-install-to-sd-card - first comment suggests using BalenaEtcher instead - Rpi's imager is pointless, since you have to download the image every single time you want to burn it!

Comment: buy a new SD Card!

Comment: @JaromandaX you don't have to download every time it does cache the download and will only redownload if a newer version is available.

Comment: OK, to be honest, I haven't found where that download is cached, and I've only used it once :p

Comment: I also downloaded the image file manually and attempted to burn that to avoid that problem :D

@Milliways that hardly seems to be the problem, it is fairly new and why would raspbian work perfectly fine?

Comment: "fails verification in sector 2048" indicates a file system problem. SD Cards are strange beasts, even newish cards can have problems - this is more obvious on large images. I have had a couple of cards with similar problems - and $10 for anew Card is cheap!

Comment: @Milliways it was unrelated to the SD card, other images would write perfectly fine.
I used balena etcher as Jaromanda suggested, and I have it working now

Comment: @Alex If you try often enough it may work (regardless of program) - I have forced writing on a faulty card - but eventually any fault will recur. The faulty block will eventually reused by the SD Card firmware. (This does not preclude the possibility of some strange Win32DiskImager fault) For $10 it is hardly worth the trouble,

Comment: @Milliways the SD card is not faulty if it works perfectly fine for every other image and program. I tried rewriting it atleast a dozen times.
Used balenaEtcher once and it works like a charm. I don't believe in such coincidences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use BalenaEtcher instead of Raspberry Pi Imager / Win32DiskImager

(As Jaromanda X's comment pointed out)